# How to enter 女人 with QQ pinyin?

Tags: pinyin, input-methods

I have installed QQ pinyin from here http://qq.pinyin.cn/

and now I am trying to enter 女人.

I am switching to CN then starting to type: "nur..."

[image]

but then I press "...e..." and input changes to

[image]

and after I enter "...n" it turns to

[image]

Nothing similar to 女人 visible.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like a pinyin ime, the word options look strange. How does 飞扬 come out when you type nur? It looks like 五笔 ime

Comment: Sorry, can't say since I am a newbie with Chinese. From my POV it accept pinyin except `u` with umlaut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nvren 
'v' replaces 'ü' in Chinese input.

Comment: Namely `u` with two dots or any `u`?

Comment: Only the umlaut (2 dot) u. For example: 旅is typed with lv, 路 is typed with lu.

Comment: only for u with two dots. Same issue on standard google android pinyin. This is only an issue for nv and lv as lue works for lve, e.g. 略 lüè.

Comment: Ok that helped. But I don't understand, if these programs do guessing, then why are they so dumb with u/v???

Comment: @Dims IMHO, that's because that the fact umlaut u is substituted by v is well known , so the programmer treats it as a common sense. Many people from south may not distinguish s/sh, c/ch, z/zh and n/ng well, so most IMEs provide options where the IME lists word options based on both consonants, instead of the consonant the user typed.

Answer (score 0):

QQ pinyin Input  "nvren"    女人

Answer (score 0):

You can use nv instead of nu, since 女 has the u with dots above it. The v in most keyboards represents the u with dots.